# ping github.com ping: cannot resolve github.com: Unknown host

Tags: macos, github, ping

All other url works but github.com give me ping: cannot resolve github.com: Unknown host
Why please i'm getting this ?

I'm on mac sierra 10.13.6

I'm not using any proxy

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you have configured an exception in your hosts file? I'm not a MacOS user but I think it is located at `/private/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks for your response on this file i have something like that


127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

Comment: That looks fine.